# A and B play a game of tennis. The situation of the game is as follows

Tags: probability

If one scores two consecutive points after a deuce he wins; if loss of a point is followed by win of a point, it is deuce.  The chance of a server to win a point is 2/3. The game is at deuce and A is serving.  Probability that A will win the game is, (serves are changed after each point)

(a) 3/5

(b) 2/5

(c) 1/2

(d) 4/5

The answer is c)
but i am getting D)
This is how i am getting D)

The probability of getting a deuce is 4/9
so probability that A wins is $$\frac{2}{3})^2[1+4/9.....]$$

Comment: That's a cool story, but you should explain **how** you are getting d. Ideally, you include your work in the post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The question shouldn't mention **tennis.** The nearest thing to what is described here is the *tie break*, but there, service changes every *two* points after the first service.

Comment: You are using the correct tennis rule that one player serves the whole game, but the question states that the serves alternate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $\frac 12$, because of the symmetry. To note this find a sequence of points in which A wins and then you can easily find a sequence of points with the same probability that wins for B and vice versa.

Comment: What about this way ,the probability of getting a deuces is 4/9.So first pb a wins or it is a deuce and then a wins and so on which is a an infinite gp

Comment: @Harish Not really consider the case when both players lose points on their serve

Comment: @Stephan4024 But in tennis doesnt a game denote winning a point(ie is from 0-0 to 1-0 is called a game) and a point is the 15-30-40-deuce???

Comment: @Harish but serves are changing after a point. For example if A loses and the B loses on his serve there's $\frac 19$ probability. If they both win on their serve there is $\frac 49$ probability, so the total probability is $\frac 59$

Comment: Okay now i get it

Comment: @Harish You can easily prove that after $2n$ points the probability of deuce is $\left(\frac 59\right)^n$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42021/discussion-between-harish-and-stefan4024).

Answer (score 4):

- $\Pr\left(A\text{ wins in }2\text{ scores}\right)+\Pr\left(A\text{ looses in }2\text{ scores}\right)=1-\Pr\left(\text{deuce after }2\text{ scores}\right)$
- $\Pr\left(A\text{ wins in }2\text{ scores}\right)=\Pr\left(A\text{ looses in }2\text{ scores}\right)$

The first is evident.

The second because in both cases one of them must win a serve point and win
a non-serve point.

Also we have:

$\Pr\left(A\text{ wins}\right)=\Pr\left(A\text{ wins in }2\text{ scores}\right)+\Pr\left(\text{deuce after }2\text{ scores}\right)\Pr\left(A\text{ wins}\right)$

Combining this leads to:

$$\Pr\left(A\text{ wins}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

case 1: if A wins the first point 
   probability of winning of A = {(2/3)*(1/3)}+{(2/3)*(2/3)*(2/3)*(1/3)}+{(2/3)*(2/3)*(2/3)*(2/3)*(2/3)*(1/3)}...... and so on.
   =2/9[1+(4/9)+(16/81).....]
the above term is a G.P.
   =2/9[1/(1-4/9)]
   =2/9[9/5]
   =2/5

case 2: if B wins the first point
   probability of winning of = {(1/3)*(1/3)*(2/3)}+{(1/3)*(1/3)*(1/3)*(1/3)*(2/3)}....and so on
the above term is also a G.P.
   =2/(3^3)[1+(1/9)+(1/81)....]
   =2/27[1/(1-(1/9)]
   =(2/27)*(9/8)
   =2/24
probability= case 1 + case 2
           = (2/5)+(2/24)
           = (48+10)/120
           = 29/60.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)